# AngularJS - watch column in table grid

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I need to watch all the clicks and input changes on my columns in a html table.

my $watch never triggerd. I don't understand ng-model="" if I use ng-repeat with tables.

```
fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k8h0owb8/7/
```

.....

EDIT

```
        <td><input type="checkbox" 

                   ng-click="clickMyCheckbox(item.checked, $index)" 
                   ng-model="item.checked" />
        </td>

        $scope.clickMyCheckbox = function(value, index) {

         console.log('click');
         console.log(value);
         console.log(index);

        };
```

my fixed fiddle looks now like this. Now I have to push it into my big sample.

[fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8h0owb8/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any wtachers, you can use `ng-model` (only) as you mentionned it.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items" >
     <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" /></td>
     <td>{{item.txt}}</td>
     <td><input type="text" size="20" maxsize="20" ng-model="item.comment" /></td>
</tr>
```

With this, it will be bind on your JSON and value will change each times you need. Moreover, you don't need extra functions on your controller at all.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0c7u33n3/)

Answer (score 0):

use either `$scope.$watch('items')` because item is not there on the controller scope.
or place `ng-change` on your column to call a function on the controller.

Personally I prefer second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your click is not logging because you have not passed the object to be logged , change the check box parameters like below (where `this` refers to `current object`)

```
ng-change="clickMyCheckbox(this)"
ng-click="clickMyCheckbox(this)"
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8h0owb8/8/)</kbd>